# Arduino and MQ-X sensor's values issue

Tags: arduino, sensors

I have these problems:

1. MQ-04 sensor remain giving value between 200-300(approx) even I am not providing any external methane gas.
2. Same issue with MQ-02 and MQ-07 remain giving smoke and carbon mono-oxide values between 25-50(approx) respectively.